# How to add active class to the navigation link in magento product view page

Tags: magento

I have Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 running, Active class for navigation (topmenu) is working fine in category and subcategory page. but when i go to product view page category and subcategory of product is not highlighting. So please suggest me how to add active class to the category and subcategory navigation link in magento product view page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Add the following jquery attribute to the li of category navigation links with the following code

```
<li data-categoryname="<?php echo "category-".$_category->getUrlKey(); ?>">
```

Step 2) Add the following jQuery code in the product view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $j(document).ready(function(){
    var classname = $j("body").attr('class').split(' ').last();
    $j('ul').find("[data-categoryname='"+classname+"']").addClass('active');
  })
</script>
```

If you inspect the body of the product view page you will see the list of class name and in that you will see the class name called "category-categoryname" at the last.